# How to maintain the fragment state in Android navigation component with BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Ex: List scroll position is not maintained in navigateUp(). Which means it recreates the fragment on back press. How to avoid that?

Comment: Can you show the logic how you are creating fragment and also please post the fragment class.